# How to Expand OS disk on a Linux VM using Cloud Shell?

Tags: linux, azure, azure-virtual-machine

I have a little problem with a production Classic VM. I reached the maximum capacity of the disk, and I need to expand it.

So I tried:

```
azure config mode arm
```

then

```
azure vm deallocate --resource-group XXX --name XXX
```

the result:

```
info:    Executing command vm deallocate
+ Looking up the VM "XXX"
error:   Virtual machine "XXX" not found under the resource group "XXX"
error:   Error information has been recorded to /home/xyz/.azure/azure.err
error:   vm deallocate command failed
```

I don't understand why there is no VM in the resource group, so I tried to list what is in the resource group^

```
azure resource list
```

and the result:

```
data:    /subscriptions/xyz/resourceGroups/XXX/providers/Microsoft.ClassicCompute/virtualMachines/XXX                           XXX                         XXX                     Microsoft.ClassicCompute/virtualMachines          westeurope  null
```

So I have a VM, but Azure can't see it.

Comment: Your question is off-topic here. You can ask on [Super User](https://superuser.com) or [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about operating system VMs and not programming. You should delete this and ask on https://unix.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to deallocate a classic VM, we should use this command `azure vm shutdown 'vnmane'` in CLI 1.0 with **ASM mode**:

```
jason@Azure:~$ azure config mode asm
info:    Executing command config mode
info:    New mode is asm
info:    config mode command OK
jason@Azure:~$ azure vm shutdown -h
help:    Shutdown the VM
help:
help:    Usage: vm shutdown [options] <name>
help:
help:    Options:
help:      -h, --help               output usage information
help:      -v, --verbose            use verbose output
help:      -vv                      more verbose with debug output
help:      --json                   use json output
help:      -d, --dns-name <name>    only show VMs for this DNS name
help:      -p, --stay-provisioned   if specified the compute resource will not be released on shutdown
help:      -s, --subscription <id>  the subscription id
help:
help:    Current Mode: asm (Azure Service Management)
jason@Azure:~$ azure vm shutdown 'jasonv'
info:    Executing command vm shutdown
+ Getting virtual machines
+ Shutting down VM
info:    vm shutdown command OK
jason@Azure:~$
```

Hope this helps:)

Comment: Hello, in the ASM mode how to increase the disk capacity?              
azure vm set \
    --resource-group myResourceGroup \
    --name myVM \
    --new-os-disk-size 50

Comment: @Dhafer Azure CLI 1.0 ASM mode does not support expand OS disk, we can use Azure powershell (ASM) command `update-azuredisk -DiskName "jasonvm6063" -Label resized -ResizedSizeInGB 100` to expand it. for now, Azure cloud shell does not support ASM powershell, we should install Azure powershell on our local PC then use Powershell to expand it. more information about powershell expand OS disk, please refer to this [link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/madan/2015/11/02/resizing-azure-vm-os-or-data-disk/).